# Socket printing weird

Tags: c++, sockets

I am brand new to using sockets in the winapi, but I have this code and I am trying to print all data coming from a socket, but when I try printing it it comes out as a jumbled mix of symbols what am I doing wrong.  I have looked around for examples on how to do this but none of the examples show how to print the data after it is collected from the buffer.

```
do 
{
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
printf("%.*s", recvbuflen, recvbuf);
} 
while (iResult > 0);
```

ok guys i have changed my code to this

```
do 
{
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1000000
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
ssize_t len = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
printf("%.*s", recvbuflen, recvbuf);
} 
while (iResult > 0);
```

but now it doesnt seem to print all information from socket just first part

Comment: You're ignoring the return value from `recv`. Never, ever do that. Please add error checking & deal with received length properly, and edit your question if you still have problems after that. (The sending code might be required, problem could be on that end too.)

Comment: how do i deal with the received length

Comment: Check the man page for `recv`. It returns the received lenght _if_ it succeeded. You need to take that return value into account.

Comment: If you read 10 bytes for printing 512, you gonna display the 502 last char not initialized of the `recvbuf` var. Mat is right, check the return value of `recv ()`

Comment: Your "updated" code adds a `recv` call that eats up to DEFAULT_BUFLEN bytes of data, saves a return value thereafter completely ignored, and goes right back to the same fail-code you had before. And you expect that to *work*? Did you *really* ***read*** the comments left here and the answer below? Did you read the man page for `recv()`? What did you learn from it? Finally, unless all the data incoming is asci chars, you probably won't like the results of your print. bin2asci conversion may be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring length of what you have received:

```
ssize_t len = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
if (len > 0)
{
    printf("%.*s", (int)len, recvbuffer);
}
else
{
    break; // error or EOF
}
```

Comment: +1 This seemingly simple snippet is very likely what the OP is really looking for, though I fear they may still be in for a possible surprise if `recvbuffer` contains non-printable data.

Comment: The code posted above still isn't enough to fix the problem, as recvbuffer may not be terminated with a NUL byte.  You should replace recvbuflen with (recvbuflen-1) in the recv() call, and also put a recvbuf[len]='\0'; just before the printf().

Comment: @JeremyFriesner do you know how the `%*` (note asterisk) prefix works with `printf()` when printing a string? Do you see how *two* parameters are passed, but there is only one format specifier? Hmmm.... might wanna check that. See [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and in particular the options immediately *above* the format specifier chart. `%*` is really handy sometimes, and this is one of those times.

Comment: @WhozCraig according to your link, the * character lets you specify a minimum field width, such that the string will be padded out with spaces if is less than (len) characters long.  I don't see anything in there about truncating the string if it is greater than (len) characters long (which if (recvbuffer) wasn't NUL-terminated, it might be)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The missing char on my comment (and the one I use so often I don't even think about it anymore) is the `.` prefix. As in `"%.*s"`, as the OP has shown in their code. It is the *precision* modifier used in conjunction with the parameterized length value. With it, the precision note of the `s` modifier comes into play, as it should. I apologize for not including the format string verbatim in my comment and thus causing any misdirection. Totally my bad. In this case, the answer should include this, but does not, so technically it isn't quite right.

Answer (score 2):

As Valeri and others have stated you should **not** ignore the return value of `recv`. However by default all sockets are blocking and I see no mention that you are using non-blocking sockets. So unless the connection is severed `recv` will wait until the buffer is full before returning. I don't think that is causing your problem.

If you are sending random data over the wire the results you are getting are exactly what one would expect. Any character value above 127 called [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is likely to appear to be a strange symbol. Character values below 32 also known as [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) may cause a beep or a character erase to occur.

Comment: +1 I'm somewhat partial to the form-feeds myself =P, though it will not wait for the buffer to be full be necessarily (last I checked).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahhh I forgot about that. I sent a few to my sisters printer in the next state. I'll just tell her it's invisible ink.